# Repair database command

Tags: mongodb

How do I run the `repairDatabase()` on a database? Is it like `Database1.repairDatabase()` in the `mongod` or just `db.repairDatabase()`. I'm confused about the basic nature of this command and how it should be called on a specific database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use my_db
db.repairDatabase();
```

Should do it.

As explained here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/#repairDatabase